# Basic terminal commands not working after trying to install Composer

Tags: macos, terminal, composer-php

My mac terminal is completely dysfunctional! Every time I open terminal I get this message:

```
-bash: export: `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10/bin/:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin': not a valid identifier
```

The problem came about a while ago, I believe I was attempting to install composer to work with MAMP.

Today I started a beginner tutorial on how to use the Terminal and almost every command does not work such as the basic `mkdir` , `ls` , and `touch` (to make folder, list items, and make a file respectively), (screenshot attached).

I have already tried deleting the `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Terminal.plist` file. Your help is greatly appreciated.

I am working with Mac OS X 10.10.2

[screenshot of terminal after making basic commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/goSlC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have an error in your `.bash_profile` or other startup script. Open it on terminal using `vi ~/.bash_profile` or some other editor of your choice and comment out that line, then type `source .bash_profile` to reload it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I try that command I get this: `adams-imac:/ Lewisona$ vi ~/.bash_profile
-bash: vi: No such file or directory`

Comment: try editing from finder. you'll need to show hidden files first

Comment: if vim/vi/nano doesn't work -> your PATH variable is broken. Thats what export command means. Give us your "echo $PATH" output from terminal. @leeor is correct. He is trying to fix config of your bash

Comment: @MarekH When I hit return after "echo $PATH" I just get a blank line :(

Comment: So we are trying now to fix it enter "   export PATH="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10/bin/:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin"   " Does it work? Try "echo $PATH" now

Comment: @MarekH It returns this: "-bash: export: `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10/bin/:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin‌​:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin': not a valid identifier" I really appreciate your help

Comment: @MarekH this is what happens when I mix and match the two things you asked me to do i.e "export $PATH" https://www.dropbox.com/s/i9ysqv6s1yixy1r/Screen%20Shot%202015-10-11%20at%202.19.21%20PM.png?dl=0 (link to screenshot)

Comment: declare -x PATH="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10/bin/:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbi‌​n‌​:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin" what about this one?

Comment: So I have typo there (one of apostrophes is addtional)

Comment: @MarekH after that I get: "adams-imac:~ Lewisona$ " with the ability to type

Comment: @MarekH alright thank you for your help anyway. Do you have any last suggestions of how I could fix this?

Comment: The mistake you do is either you don't put apostrophes and from screenshot i see that you have spaces in the export command -> this is why it doesn't wokr

Comment: @MarekH Sorry I wasn't aware of those mistakes, here is a new link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/251ccpslqq02tw3/Screen%20Shot%202015-10-11%20at%202.38.51%20PM.png?dl=0

Comment: It's bit painful if you don't try delete those space gaps http://postimg.org/image/8t3yqdtk9/d6ccd517/ Once you have this you should be able to use those commands + use @leeor solution to find the "space" or other mistake in the config startup profile of terminal

Comment: @MarekH I am so sorry, I have absolutely no idea how I keep overlooking them, or how they even got there in the first place :/ Anyway thank you for being so patient with me here it is again (pretty sure theres no spaces this time) https://www.dropbox.com/s/rzp7fkltpfhm02e/Screen%20Shot%202015-10-11%20at%203.07.14%20PM.png?dl=0

Comment: @MarekH oh wow, those basic commands are working now! When I do: `vi ~/.bash_profile` I get: `export PATH= /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10/bin/:$PATH` + (multiple lines of `~`) + `"~/.bash_profile" 2L, 62C` . I do not know how or what to comment out

Comment: Didn't this solve your whole problem? you should also remove the space after `PATH=`

Comment: @leeor I have done that, how can I save it now? also would it not be better to delete that line as I have since deleted mamp